# Identifying the type of missing data and the post hoc test that can be carried out for Skillings Mack test

Tags: nonparametric, missing-data, paired-data, post-hoc, friedman-test

I have a non-normal paired sample dataset. Each row represents a dog that has been tested for an experiment. Each dog was provided with three cues (treatments): 5s cue (aka only face cue), vocalone (face + vocal cue), vocaltwo (face + vocalcue*2). The cues were provided consecutively. Depending on their behaviour, they were given a score. Each score was calculated by adding all the behaviours displayed during that particular cue treatment (e.g. pricked ears + left tail wag = -3). A score of 0 stands for neutrality. The experiment was stopped when the dog approached the experimenter. In the highlighted rows, the dog approached the experimenter in vocalone treatment. Since the experiment stopped at that point, vocal two treatment for that dog has no score. In other cases, the dog may have approached in the 5s cue treatment and hence both vocalone and vocaltwo has no scores for that dog. My questions are as follows:

1. Is it correct to assume that the missing data here can be classed as "Missing data at random"?
2. If yes, and I perform a Skillings- Mack test, what would be an appropriate post-hoc test if the omnibus test returns significance (p < 0.05, in my case)? I have been thinking of carrying out either Nemenyi or Conover pairwise comparisons with Holm corrections like in Friedman. Will one of these work?

[image]